# aws-cloudwatch expression attribute

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-cloudwatch, metrics, hpa, keda

Using [aws-cloudwatch](https://keda.sh/docs/2.11/scalers/aws-cloudwatch/) trigger with KEDA for auto scaling and not sure what the `expression` attribute is! Isn't supposed to return the value of the expected metrics/dimension at polling time? If yes, why do we still need other attributes like `metricCollectionTime`, `metricStat`, and `metricStatPeriod`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1:
Specify `expression` - The docs say that it's "Optional, Required when dimensionName & dimensionValue are not specified". However, it could say  `namespace`, `metricName`, `dimensionName`, and `dimensionValue`.
e.g.

```
 ...
 expression: SELECT AVG("my_metric_name") FROM "Metric/Namespace" WHERE dimension1 = "dimension1value"
```

Option 2: `namespace`, `metricName`, `dimensionName`, `metricStat`, and `dimensionValue` should be specified in place of `expression`.

e.g. The equivalent to the above would be:

```
 ...
 metricName: metric_name
 namespace: Metric/Namespace
 dimensionName: dimension1
 metricStat: Average
 dimensionValue: dimension1value
```

`metricCollectionTime` and `metricStatPeriod` are both needed regardless of which of the above two options is used, because they determine the time frame for which to look for metrics, whereas the above options have nothing to do with the timeframe associated to each metric.

- `metricCollectionTime` is how far back to look for metrics
- `metricStatPeriod` is how far back to aggregate metrics which are retrieved (must be less than or equal to `metricCollectionTime`). The aggregation function depends on `metricStat` or `expression`.